# Enable ScrollViewReader to scroll to an already visible view

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Given this implementation for a sample chat app, I'd like to scroll to the last message when the keyboard is presented.

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { reader in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(1..<50, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text(number.description)
                }
                
                Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 1).id("last")
            }.onReceive(Publishers.keyboardState) { state in // Publisher listening to keyboard NSNotifications
                withAnimation {
                    reader.scrollTo("last")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation works great if the content of the scroll view is at any other vertical position than already at the bottom. My guess is that SwiftUI understands that the view with id `last` is already fully visible when the content is scrolled to the bottom by the user, so the `reader.scrollTo("last")` call is discarded when the keyboard is presented. Any workarounds aside from adding a delay before calling the `reader.scrollTo(` API?